# replacing lines in file

Tags: python, arrays, replace, lines

I have a file that looks like this (columns ar coordinates x,y,z and lines represents some objects):

```
 1.02      0.63      0.0003 
-1.34      0.61      0.0002
 0.0       0.0       0.0
-1.91      0.25      0.87
-1.32      1.70      0.0
 0.02     -1.12     -0.06
```

I want to:

1) multiply second line by 3;

2) find the differences between new values in line 2 and old valuesn(those I got by multiplying) in the same columns (i.e. the difference between second line's column one new value and old value, secons line's column two new value and old etc.)

3)replace values in line 2 by new values;

4) add the differences I got to the values in lines 4 and 5.

So the output should look like:

```
 1.02      0.63      0.0003
-4.02      1.83      0.0006
 0.0       0.0       0.0
-4.59      1.47      0.8704
-4.00      2.92      0.0004
-2.66      0.10     -0.0596
```

What I got so far is:

```
import numpy as np 

a=np.loadtxt('geometry.in')
C=s[1]
b=np.array((a)[C]) #read second line as array
x_old=b[0] #define coordinate x
y_old=b[1] #define coordinate y
z_old=b[2] #define coordinate z

C_new=b*3 #multiplying all line by 3

x=C_new[0] #defining new values in columns of the line
y=C_new[1]
z=C_new[2]

dx=x-x_old #the differene that I need to add to the first column of lines 4 and 5
dy=y-y_old
dz=z-z_old
```

I tried a.replace(x_old, x) but it didn't work and I got really stuck in this.

Comment: Is this homework? Why are you doing it with numpy?

Comment: No, it's not homework. I am runnging some calculations and gave lots of files like this I need to change. I am using numpy because I thought I am using arrays. Sorry, I am very nee in python so I am probably doing stupid things.

Comment: Please use proper spelling and grammar. -1

Comment: Your code violates PEP 8 (the official python style guide) in many ways. Get an editor like PyCharm (it's free) that can highlight and fix these errors for you.

Comment: You probably don't need `numpy`.  You can use lists in regular python, they are similar to arrays in other languages.

Comment: @BrigitaP. you don't need numpy to use arrays. Just use the builtin list syntax. (google it!)

Comment: @BrigitaP. You need to give me a scenario that will universally work with  any sample files. How do the instructions repeat? Edit your question with an examle of a file with coordinates and a file that has correct output. Calculate it by hand if you can't do it with Python.

Comment: Your output is a puzzle.  Take the second line, you appear to have multiplied by 3, but if you are going to subtract the original values, then why not just multiply by 2 instead?  The sample output only appears to multiple by 3.

Comment: I want to substract the difference just from 4th and 5th lines. The second line has to remain just multiplied by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use numpy, here is an example you can work on:
load the whole data as a numpy array "ao"

```
    old2 = ao[1,:]
    new2 = ao[1,:]*3
    diff = new2 - old2
    ao[1,:] = new2
    ao[3:,:] = ao[3:,:] + diff
```